# How to define a CAS in database as external resource for an annotator in uimaFIT?

Tags: nlp, data-mining, information-retrieval, uima

I am trying to structure my a data processing pipeline using uimaFit as follows:

`[annotatorA]` => `[Consumer to dump annotatorA's annotations from CAS into DB]`

`[annotatorB (should take on annotatorA's annotations from DB as input)]`=>`[Consumer for annotatorB]`

The driver code:

```
   /* Step 0: Create a reader */
    CollectionReader readerInstance= CollectionReaderFactory.createCollectionReader(
            FilePathReader.class, typeSystem,
            FilePathReader.PARAM_INPUT_FILE,"/path/to/file/to/be/processed");

   /*Step1: Define Annotoator A*/
    AnalysisEngineDescription annotatorAInstance=
           AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(
                    annotatorADbConsumer.class, typeSystem, 
                    annotatorADbConsumer.PARAM_DB_URL,"localhost",
                    annotatorADbConsumer.PARAM_DB_NAME,"xyz",
                    annotatorADbConsumer.PARAM_DB_USER_NAME,"name",
                    annotatorADbConsumer.PARAM_DB_USER_PWD,"pw");
    builder.add(annotatorAInstance);

    /* Step2: Define binding for annotatorB to take 
         what-annotator-a put in DB above as input */

    /*Step 3: Define annotator B */
    AnalysisEngineDescription annotatorBInstance =
            AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(
                    GateDateTimeLengthAnnotator.class,typeSystem)
    builder.add(annotatorBInstance);

    /*Step 4: Run the pipeline*/
    SimplePipeline.runPipeline(readerInstance, builder.createAggregate());
```

Questions I have are:

1. Is the above approach correct?
2. How do we define the depencdency of annotatorA's output in annotatorB in step 2?

Is the approach suggested at https://code.google.com/p/uimafit/wiki/ExternalResources#Resource_injection
, the right direction to achieve it ?

Comment: Not sure I understand it right: Annotator A creates annotation based on the DB's contents, right? If so, then it should be a CollectionReader, not an AnnotationEngine...

Comment: No, annotatorA reads content from CAS, where the default SOFA contains the text from a file. The CollectionReader defined in `Step: 0` updates the CAS.....I want to know if there is a way to define and enforce the dependency of annotatorA's output in annotatorB while defining my pipeline...TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the dependency with [`@TypeCapability`](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-2.1.0/api/org/apache/uima/fit/descriptor/TypeCapability.html) like this:

```
@TypeCapability(inputs = { "com.myproject.types.MyType", ... }, outputs = { ... })
public class MyAnnotator extends JCasAnnotator_ImplBase {
    ....
}
```

Note that it defines a contract at the annotation level, not the engine level (meaning that any Engine could create `com.myproject.types.MyType`).

I don't think there are ways to **enforce** it.

I did create some code to check that an Engine is provided with the right required Annotations in the upstream of a pipeline, and prints an error log otherwise (see [Pipeline.checkAndAddCapabilities() and Pipeline.addCapabilities()](https://github.com/BlueBrain/bluima/blob/8f41d21728fcd12ed4c2feb9578e3487c588a475/modules/bluima_scripting/src/main/java/ch/epfl/bbp/uima/laucher/Pipeline.java) ). Note however that it will only work if all Engines define their TypeCapabilities, which is often not the case when one uses external Engines/libraries.